# What browsers currently support the 'range' input?

Tags: validation, html, cross-browser, range

I can't seem to find anything on google about this. I know you can pretty much rule out IE. I know webkit supports it but what else do you know?

Comment: According to CanIUsem, IE supports range input since Version 10 which was released almost two years ago :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, apparently (Desktop) Safari, Chrome and Opera support `range` inputs, according to [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/forms.html#type-range).

Comment: Ok great thanks, don't suppose you know the css3 selectors for styling it in webkit and opera?

Comment: Nope, sorry, haven't played around with it much. :3

Comment: And Safari on iOS 5.1 (at least) supports it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this question has been here quite a while, but I wanted to add this anyway.
Regarding a question about browser support, a good source is always the *caniuse.com* website.

In this case, you can find the current, past and expected future support for the *range input* here:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-range