# Input Range Slider

Tags: css, html, input, cross-browser, range

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What browsers currently support the ‘range’ input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944552/what-browsers-currently-support-the-range-input)

Is there a way to show the slider in all major browsers when using the input type range?

I am using this code:

```
<input id="Priority" type="range" min="1" max="5" step="1" value="3" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
```

I know it works in Chrome but when I use internet explorer or firefox, it only shows a text box instead of a slider.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it would be to use a jqueryui slider: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Answer (score 0):

I have found this on GitHub. If you save your files to GitHub, you can fork it from this person's page. They give permission to use the code. My range slider shows in all browsers now.

https://github.com/fryn/html5slider/blob/master/html5slider.js

Note: You must include the copyright notice:

Copyright (c) 2010-2011 Frank Yan, http://frankyan.com

in your page or just save the entire page with copyright notice as a separate .js file like I did.